# WPF ListView Stretch Width To Grid Column

Tags: wpf

I have a grid with two columns each with a width of `1*` to be of equal widths. Inside the left-most column, I have a listview but for some reason I can't get the width to automatically stretch to the width of the grid column.  I've tried all kinds of things like `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"` and `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"` both of which were suggested as possible fixes to this issue... but they don't seem to address my issue.  Here's my code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path= Loads}" Grid.Column="0" MinHeight="20" MaxHeight="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="6,-3,0,0" SelectedItem="{Binding Path= CurrentLoad}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="local:Loads">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Width="26" Height="26">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" Width="24" Height="24" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="9" Margin="3,6,3,3"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,-2,6,0" Grid.Column="1"></StackPanel>
</Grid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left"
```

Well, there's your problem.

Comment: Yep.  That solved it.  I knew I was just missing something stupid.  Thanks.